# how to put some variable in one variable?

Tags: c++, variables

```
int a=1,b=2,c=3;
```

how can i put variable in one variable like 123 or anything else 132 111 123 i want to make a game i need to use some variable and put them into one variable to verify them with ((if)) like this:

```
if(num==abc)
```

....
how can i put a,b,c in one variable? or if it cant possiable say some way to put it in ((if)).

Comment: First you need to learn some basics. Buy a good C or C++book first.

Comment: According the grammar of C++ you can't do it. You maybe learn more about it before try to make a game.  And `if(num==a*100+b*10+c)` could achieve your current need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all explain what game are you making. As far as I could make it you want to make a 3 digit no. then I think you know how to make a three digit no.

100*a+10*b+c.